# Script trigger works on Google Sheet but is not getting called on Android mobile app, including onEdit

Tags: google-sheets

I have created a simple function in google apps script which work seamless on Browser, but not working on Google sheets' Android App or iOS Tablet. After exploring, tried the onEdit(e) function too, but the function is not called at all on Mobile or iPad, while works fine on Browser.

Request inputs on how to make this happen. This is urgent towards completing my project, as this will be used at store outlets, with consultant/stylist using iPad / mobiles.

```
 function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()=='Profile_Card') {

    if(e.range.getA1Notation()=='A1' && e.value=="Select_Filters") {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Success! Moving to Select Filters.');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Select_Filters").activate();
      e.range.setValue("");
      //you less than 30 seconds to run a function here
    }
    if(e.range.getA1Notation()=='A1' && e.value=="Search_Client") {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('You Clicked A2. You have less than 30 seconds to run a function here');
      e.range.setValue(" ");
    }
  }
  else{
    return;
  }
}
```